# SVGPan inside a div

Tags: svg, raphael

I'm using SVGPan.js from cyberz.org to zoom and pan a svg file. It works well on its own,
but when i try to display the svg inside a div, it doesnt work. The SVG is not displayed.
I tried using Raphael.js, and the raphael-svg-import plugin. When i try the raphael-svg-import demo, an error is thrown everytime, something like "The VG you entered is not valid! Type error, Raphael.deg() is not a function". Also, it seems that only the demo works. When I try another svg file, a blank page is displayed.

So my question is,
1. Is there a way to bound the svg file with the SVGPan script inside a div?
or
2. Is there a way to import the svg file using raphael-svg-import without an error?

Answer (score 0):

i accomplished svg zoom & pan within a div using http://keith-wood.name/svg.html and https://github.com/talos/jquery-svgpan

```
<div id="canvas"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready ( function () {
    $('#canvas').svg({ loadURL: 'svg.xml', onLoad: loadDone });
    });
function loadDone() {
    $('#canvas svg').svgPan('viewport')
    }
</script>
```